# When i rewrite my url with .htaccess, i get a 500 internal server error

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

My htaccess file is looking like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /index.php?id=$1 [L]
```

i am trying to rewrite:

example.com/index.php?id=foo

to

example.com/foo

this one, as far as i know.. should do the trick, but it gives me an internal server error. i have tried checking the error logs.. but nothing is there, (Dont know if my provider for some reason doesnt show me the logs).

But do any of you know why this is not working? 
or do you know another solution that could work?

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Safeguard your rule with `RewriteCond` to avoid rewriting for existing files and directories:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ /index.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
```